# Dynamic dropdown options not showing in IE7

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

We have a dropdown list that is dynamically populated using javascript (below). But it doesn't show in IE7.

This is the code that populates the options:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
        var today= new Date();
        var year= today.getFullYear();
        var val =0;
        t2= 51;
        grad_yr                 = document.getElementById("grad_yr");
        grad_yr.options[0]  = new Option("Year",val,false,false);
        var y=year;
        var yy=y;       
        for (var i=1; i <t2 ; i++) {
            grad_yr.options[i] = new Option(y,y);
            y=yy-1;
            yy--;
        }
        }
</script>
```

This is the HTML:

```
<select name="grad_yr" id="grad_yr"></select>
```

What could be wrong?

---

EDIT: Ok, nevermind. Apparently, the list is actually being populated. It's just that we have another javascript that sort of moves the position of the options that's why it looks hidden. Thanks anyway!

Comment: `var y=yy ... y=yy-1; yy--;` gave me an aneurysm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a name collision by using the same global variable name for your `grad_yr` variable and the select element.  Comment out the line where you are pulling your `grad_yr` from the document by ID, as it is unneccessary:

```
//grad_yr = document.getElementById("grad_yr");
grad_yr.options[0] = new Option("Year", val, false, false);
```

Or, if you really do need to have a variable reference, just give your variable a different name, like this (or some such):

```
grad_yrVar = document.getElementById("grad_yr");
grad_yrVar.options[0] = new Option("Year", val, false, false);
...
 for (var i = 1; i < t2; i++) {
     grad_yrVar.options[i] = new Option(y, y);
     y = yy - 1;
     yy--;
 }
```

...and it should work.

Comment: What happens now is that it shows in IE7 (dropdown) but without the select name (which is "Year"). In IE8, the select name appears, but still the dropdown isn't being populated.

Comment: Hmmm....it is working for me in IE 7 and 8. Are you using "Compatability Mode" and the developer tools (F12 key) in IE 8 for testing? On additional thought: change your `grad_yr.options[i] = new Option()` statements to `grad_yr.add(new Option())` instead and see if that works...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var grad_yr = document.getElementById("grad_yr");
```